# Comparison of Board Shape between Arduino MEGA and Arduino DUE

Tags: arduino-mega, arduino-due, shields, pcb-design

I'm using KiCAD to design boards, and while it has a lot of Arduino templates, it doesn't have one for the Arduino Due. Now, I've did some searching, and it looks like the Arduino MEGA is very similar to the Arduino DUE, not the specifications, but the number of I/O pins and the overall shape of the board. I couldn't find a straight answer, so I decided to ask here: Can the template of the Arduino MEGA be used as a template for the Arduino DUE when designing custom 'shields' and such based on the number of I/O pins and overall layout?

Answer (score 2):

> The Due has the same footprint as the Mega 2560.

[source](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoDue#toc11)